# How can we get the pipeline to read columns with special characters?

Tags: pipeline, kedro

I am using the "usecols" parameter to get some columns of a .xlsx file (I am using the xls_local.py file from the Kedro tutorial) but the program says that "usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found:" and it only shows the columns that have special characters. How can I fix this, please? Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this isn't a `kedro` issue, but a `pandas.read_excel` issue, which is what `kedro` uses under the hood. This seems to be broken in `pandas` itself, and a workaround is to reference the columns using letters instead, so something like `usecols='A:D'` and then you can rename the columns to what they should be by doing `df.columns = ["colname with special characters", "b", "c", "d"]` for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Do you have a similar suggestion for a .csv file, please?

Comment: @sofiacosta29 try passing in `encoding='utf-8'` or `encoding='latin1'` into load_args for csv's. Also, if this answer answered your question, feel free to mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know that there was an "accept mark". Done!
Also, the usecols= 'A:D' worked perfectly. So, I didn't have to use the encodings for the csv's but I would like to select all columns with the "usecols" again. Since the 'A:D' reference doesn't work anymore, do you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: If you want to select all the columns (i.e read in the whole excel/csv file) you should probably use `encoding=` and not use `usecols`, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I have had some errors before because of the selected columns in the parameters.yml file (because they didn't match the usecols parameter), but those are not a concern anymore, so I don't need usecols in this specific case. Thank you very much!